# Using crate's HTTP API to insert an array of objects : error 4003

Tags: json, http, post, crate

I’m trying to insert a row using Crate's 2.1.8 HTTP endpoint but it fails systematically with error 4003:
My table contains a column which is an array of objects and it fails with error 4003 : “SQLActionException[ColumnValidationException: Validation failed for arr: ‘[{\“t\“:1}, {\“z\“:\“foo\“}]’ cannot be cast to type object_array]”

here’s the table creation :
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS “doc”.“test” (
   “arr” ARRAY(OBJECT (DYNAMIC)),
   “name” STRING
)

now here’s my json :

{“stmt”:“INSERT INTO \“test\” (\“name\“,\“arr\“) VALUES (?,?)“, “args”:[“test”, “[{\“t\“:1}, {\“z\“:\“foo\“}]“]}

and my command to post the request : wget --header “Content-Type: application/json” --post-file query_test.json -O - ’http://localhost:4200/_sql?types&error_trace=true'

The result is:
4003 : “SQLActionException[ColumnValidationException: Validation failed for arr: ‘[{\“t\“:1}, {\“z\“:\“foo\“}]’ cannot be cast to type object_array]”

If I run this from the web console : INSERT INTO “test” (“name”,“arr”) VALUES (‘test’, [{“t”=1}, {“z”=‘foo’}]); 
It works fine  ... any idea of what I’m doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the surrounding quotes of your array argument value and don't escape the quotes inside your array like:

```
{"stmt":"INSERT INTO \"test\" (\"name\",\"arr\") VALUES (?,?)", "args":["test", [{"t":1}, {"z":"foo"}]]}
```

otherwise it's a JSON string value not an array and so will CrateDB interpret this as a string.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the answer, this solved my problem. I was misled into using a string by the fact that for objects I had also used strings to transmit them and crate was processing them fine... Now I'm transferring both arrays and objets as native json and it works.